# Can a symbolic-ref in git reference the current upstream branch?

Tags: git

I can do this with git:

```
echo "ref: HEAD" > .git/h
```

and then I can use “h” in place of head in every place that accepts a commit-ish, e.g. `git log h` or `git show-branch h origin/master`.

Is it possible to do the same for the upstream branch of HEAD? It is represented by `@{u}` (or `HEAD@{upstream}` in the long form), say `git log @{u}`, `git rebase --onto @{u}` or `git show-branch HEAD @{u}`.

Trying to put any of these as a symbolic-ref like this:

```
echo "ref: HEAD@{upstream}" > .git/u
```

will result in an error:

```
$ git show u
warning: ignoring dangling symref u.
warning: ignoring dangling symref u.
fatal: ambiguous argument 'u': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do that; use `git symbolic-ref` to create symbolic references.  For instance, `git symbolic-ref u HEAD` is the "correct" command to create `.git/u` as a symbolic reference to `HEAD` (which is in turn a symbolic reference to the current branch, unless `HEAD` is detached).

As things work now, though, you can't make a symbolic reference point to something that requires additional parsing.  **This means you can't get what you want: specifically, no variant of `HEAD@{upstream}` will work here.**  The content of a symbolic ref has to be the name of another reference, so that git can resolve it easily, without any of the fancy "peeling" process that `git rev-parse` performs on user-supplied names (including names that are themselves indirect, like `HEAD`).  This is probably because symbolic references are something of an orphan step-child, as the saying goes: they've had enough work put in to them to make them work for `HEAD` to contain a branch-name, but little additional work.

Comment: I appreciate the tip about symbolic-ref rather than creating it myself, but I don't think this solves my problem. I don't need `u` to be an alias to `HEAD`, but to `HEAD@{upstream}` (aka `@{u}`).

Comment: If I run `git symbolic-ref u '@{u}'`, I got the exact same errors I reported in the problem.

Comment: "As things work now, though, you can't make a symbolic reference point to something that requires additional parsing." That means that `@{u}` is simply **not valid** as the contents of a symbolic ref. As the Rolling Stones sang, you can't always get what you want.

Comment: Thanks. If you edit your answer to say this is impossible, I can mark it as correct answer.

Comment: It already says that, but I agree it could be clearer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not only using [`git symbolic-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref) is preferable (as detailed in [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32855177/6309)), its code has been optimized with Git 2.36 (Q2 2022):

See [commit 0a7b387](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0a7b38707d5d5c8a7baeb88a85d6259cee4f4e4d), [commit 1553f5e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1553f5e76c72243f61b454412b651706a869388f), [commit cd475b3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd475b3b03809b1b1c664e0dca9f16f815456719), [commit 8e55634](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8e55634b47858f036ca773f3e1d754e5dbd4bb59), [commit 4de6562](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4de656263aa195080495fc0a103351b9eaac8160) (01 Mar 2022) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
See [commit 3436340](https://github.com/git/git/commit/34363403a28ad4d0bd76c5aa7351293b6e4a4e47) (01 Mar 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6969ac6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6969ac64bf1c7bc43e897d6bfe7d2450d37e9aa9), 16 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`refs`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cd475b3b03809b1b1c664e0dca9f16f815456719): add ability for backends to special-case reading of symbolic refs
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> Reading of symbolic and non-symbolic references is currently treated the same in reference backends: we always call `refs_read_raw_ref()` and then decide based on the returned flags what type it is.
>
> This has one downside though: symbolic references may be treated different from normal references in a backend from normal references.
> The packed-refs backend for example doesn't even know about symbolic references, and as a result it is pointless to even ask it for one.
>
> There are cases where we really only care about whether a reference is symbolic or not, but don't care about whether it exists at all or may be a non-symbolic reference.
> But it is not possible to optimize for this case right now, and as a consequence we will always first check for a loose reference to exist, and if it doesn't, we'll query the packed-refs backend for a known-to-not-be-symbolic reference.
> This is inefficient and requires us to search all packed references even though we know to not care for the result at all.
>
> Introduce a new function `refs_read_symbolic_ref()` which allows us to fix this case.
>
> This function will only ever return symbolic references and can thus optimize for the scenario layed out above.
> By default, if the backend doesn't provide an implementation for it, we just use the old code path and fall back to `read_raw_ref()`.
> But in case the backend provides its own, more efficient implementation, we will use that one instead.
>
> Note that this function is explicitly designed to not distinguish between missing references and non-symbolic references.
> If it did, we'd be forced to always search the packed-refs backend to see whether the symbolic reference the user asked for really doesn't exist, or if it exists as a non-symbolic reference.

Comment: Thanks for the extra references about symbolic-ref, but I think it is not an answer to my question. I need an alias `u` that is always equivalent to `HEAD@{upstream}`, which I still can't figure out a way to achieve, using symbolic-ref or otherwise.

Comment: @AlanTam I agree. I do not see that kind of symbolic reference in the dedicated tests https://github.com/git/git/blob/75ae10bc75336db031ee58d13c5037b929235912/t/t1401-symbolic-ref.sh